Django puts AND clause to lookup "in"
Django 4.2 together with graphene-django filters is making my query return empty results
class ExampleFilterSet(FilterSet):    
    label__name__in = StringInFilter(method="filter_labels")

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = {"users__email": ["in"]}

Ideally, here it should have been OR query - where users__email in ['abc@gmail.com' , 'xyz@gmail.com'] but on debugging its simply empties the cloned queryset
It was working well with django3.1 and graphene-django 2.9.9

what do you mean by OR or AND query? you ll get those Example in which email is one of the provided filters.

Sorry for the confusion ,  I want to run query Select & from Example where users__email in ['abc@gmail.com' , 'xyz@gmail.com'] , however it isn't working @shivankgtm

I don't think Django upgrades are playing any part in this, but Graphene or (I guess) django-filters may.

@AKX agreed, do you have something around
